# IOException when insert file to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I am encountering the following issue when posting an image to google drive:

```
java.io.IOException: insufficient data written
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.close(HttpURLConnection.java:2822)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:83)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:895)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:280)
at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Insert.executeUnparsed(Drive.java:309)
at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Insert.execute(Drive.java:331)
```

I believe its related to this: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=521

Is there a way to circumvent this? I was wondering if possible to insert a file without using the resumable upload api from the google drive sdk?

Answer (score 2):

I believe i answered my own question as to how to do a direct upload:

```
Insert insert = this.driveClient.files().insert(body, mediaContent);
insert.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(true);
File result = insert.execute();
```

However, still not sure of the cause of the insufficient data written error.

Answer (score 0):

With the option setDirectUploadEnabled(false) the insert.execute() start uploading the first chunk instantly i mean before getting the minimum chunk size. you must finish the request.getPart("fleInputName") and then start the drive upload process.

I solved this with a blocking Thread like this :

```
public class GetPartThread  extends Thread {

        private HttpServletRequest request;
        private String inputAttr;

        private Part part;



        public GetPartThread(HttpServletRequest request, String inputAttr) {
            super();
            this.request = request;
            this.inputAttr = inputAttr;
        }


        @Override
        public void run(){
                synchronized(this){
                    try {
                        part = request.getPart(inputAttr);
                        notify();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }

        public Part getPart() {
            return part;
        }

        public void setPart(Part part) {
            this.part = part;
        }
```

Then use it like this with your drive upload method :

```
GetPartThread getPart = new GetPartThread(request, "templatefile");
getPart.start();
synchronized(getPart){
try{
    System.out.println("Waiting for Part upload to complete...");
    getPart.wait();
}catch(InterruptedException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Part upload Finished...");

Part part = getPart.getPart();

//Here continue with processing your "part" and upload it to drive with the method you set for uploading to drive ... }
```

This should work.

Note : Don't use setConvert(true) when using Drive Resumable Media Uploads this will throw an exception because convertion start for the first chunk uploaded to drive and not after upload completion.