# Got IOException "insufficient data written" when inserting large file into Google drive

Tags: java, io, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to insert large file into Google's drive using `google-api-services-drive` version `v2-rev93-1.16.0-rc`
I've set `setChunkSize()` for minimum in order to have my own `ProgressListener` notified more frequent. The following code is used to insert file:

```
File body = new File();
body.setTitle(filetobeuploaded.getName());
body.setMimeType("application/zip");
body.setFileSize(filetobeuploaded.length());

InputStreamContent mediaContent =
        new InputStreamContent("application/zip",
        new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filetobeuploaded)));
mediaContent.setLength(filetobeuploaded.length());

Insert insert = drive.files().insert(body, mediaContent);
MediaHttpUploader uploader = insert.getMediaHttpUploader();
uploader.setChunkSize(MediaHttpUploader.MINIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE);
uploader.setProgressListener(new CustomProgressListener(filetobeuploaded));
insert.execute();
```

After 'a while' (sometimes 200 MB sometimes 300 MB ) I got `IOException` :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: insufficient data written
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.close(HttpURLConnection.java:3213)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:81)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:960)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:482)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:390)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:418)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
```

Any ideas how to get this code working?

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to get it working from a frontend because of time constrains. The only reliable way (but a pain) is to do it from a backend using resumable upload since the backend/task queue may also be shut down while processing chunks.

Comment: Could you give me some more info about these time constraints? I can not find it in documentation.

Comment: Sorry I assumed you were calling the api from an appengine frontend.

Comment: But in any case, for large files, using a resumable upload is the best way. Thst way you can keep going after an error (network, api etc) without having to start the upload from zero.

Answer (score 0):

Does 'a while' happen to mean 1 hour? In this case you are probably experiencing the following bug:

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5124

Answer (score 0):

This issue is only for Drive Resumable Media upload. check this reply .. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30796105/4576135

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score 0):

For me this meant "you are doing a POST and specified a content length, but then the stream you uploaded wasn't long enough to match that content length" (a closed bytearray stream, in my case, closed because previously used to basically "exhausted" already, as it were).